# He spent $300 Ving

Tags: grammaticality, present-participles

I made up the following sentence:

> He spent $300 talking to a counsellor.

But a native speaker said "One doesn't spend $300 in talking to a counsellor. The fees for the session(s) may be $300, the costs of long distance phone calls to a counsellor may be $300, but no native speaker of English would write the sentence as you have written it."

Could someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: The missing preposition is the possible culprit, as it (or *in* as your critic did) gives a sense of "during the course of." Try using *on* instead, which would mean the expense incurred for a purpose in a broad sense: "He spent $300 **on** talking to a counselor." HTH.

Comment: @Kris It certainly sounds more "proper" to include the preposition, but the original line sounds fine to my ear, especially in a colloquial context. The implication of the sentence is also very clear - that $300 was spent on counselling services (any other interpretation would be stretching it). I'd say the "native speaker" is way off base on this one.

Comment: It seems that 'no native speaker of English would' should rather be 'only in certain registers would native speakers of English'. Has 'a native speaker' a similar problem accepting 'He spent three hours looking at the stars', where the expenditure/time=money metaphor is used, and where 'in' and 'on' don't sound very idiomatic?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Without entirely agreeing with this native speaker, I can see what he meant. You do spend time looking at the stars; you do not spend money talking, unless you feed money into a slot on the counsellor. *Spending $300 on counselling* would be a reasonable alternative.

Comment: There is nothing really wrong with the original statement.  One could elaborate as to what the charges were specifically for, but that's probably unnecessary detail.

Comment: @TimLymington Please don't wrongly instruct 'You do not ...'; the prepositionless construction is in use in non-metaphorical cases: 'In the last third of the twentieth century, the [US] spent more than one trillion dollars protecting its environment' /  'We spend thousands of dollars protecting our homes' /  'The Metropolitan Police spends millions of pounds protecting royals'/ 'the NHS spent a record 113 million pounds hiring agency staff last year' [all early Google returns]. And 'talking to a lawyer', as TRomano points out, is a synonym for 'consulting ...', like 'talk to the police'.

Comment: @Edwin: My point was explicitly that while you can spend money hiring a lawyer or consulting one (or indeed protecting one), spending money talking to one rather than on talking can be seen as not strictly correct. And I don't see the relevance of your last sentence, unless you think that all synonyms take the same preposition.

Comment: @TimLymington There are two senses for 'talk to a lawyer' (unless you include the 'give a good talking to' sense): the basic have a conversation with a lawyer, and sense 3b given at AHD:
To consult or confer with someone: I talked with the doctor. Thus you can spend money consulting with / talking to a lawyer, but not spend money having a lovely chat with a lawyer.

Answer (score 5):

> He spent $300 talking to a counsellor.

Apart from "counsellor", it sounds like idiomatic American English to me.

**He spent $500 talking to a lawyer.**

Comment: "Talking to a lawyer" is a collocation that means "discussing a legal matter with hired counsel".

Comment: "Talking to a counsellor" is a collocation that means "discussing a personal matter with a designated (and potentially hired) psychologist."